# Push Notification Certificate with iOS Auto Signing

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-app-signing

I have started using **automatic management of app signing** within iOS application. Certificate and Provisioning Profile both get managed properly for Developer and Distribution environment.

[image]

But how to deal with Push Notification setting with Auto settings in xCode. Before I was doing all these process manually like certificate upload at App IDs section. But using Auto settings upto now detected nothing.

[image]

Its still in **Configurable** status. So is this process happened automatically through xCode or its still manual process. Please guide me into this so I can move ahead towards testing section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic management of app signing is used to make it easily to run a newly created app without hassle of creating certificates and provision profiles , but to establish push notifications you have to manually create App ID and all that stuff

Comment: Then for push notification setting - which CertificateRequest file, I require to use ? because I done nothing and on Apple Developer account certificate and profile generated.

Comment: in keychain you select requestCertificateFromAcertificateAuthority like usual and upload it to your account and download push certificate

Comment: I am curious if this is still the case after Apple made some changes. I updated the App ID in developer.apple.com and it looks like in my Xcode the auto signing is pulling from that. So do I need to make a manual provisioning profile or can I just let Xcode take care of this?